# Est-ce qu'il y a un glissement de sens si on traduit l'adjectif « vrai » par « yes » en anglais?

Tags: sens, traduction, anglais, adjectifs

Since "vrai" is an adjectif and "yes" is not, I'm guessing that its meaning become not really the same. Here's the example:

> A: Bonjour ! Vous avez l'air très fatiguée C!
>
> B: C'est vrai ! Pourquoi ?
>
> C: Je n'ai pas pu dormir la nuit dernière.

and translated to:

> A: Hello! you look so tired C!
>
> B: Yes! What happened?
>
> C: I couldn't sleep last night.

But I can't find the reason why the meaning feels different. Therefore I'm confused, is there actually any glissement or not?

Comment: Isn't `it's true` the closest translation of `c'est vrai` ? So the difference between "yes" and "vrai" is the same than "yes" and "true".

Comment: yeah, i believe so too, the closest translation would be better to be "c'est vrai". but this book that im reading translated it to "yes". and i cant figure out wether its different or not because the way i look at it, it doesnt have 100% same impression

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Le sens est très proche, mais il y a une légère nuance dans « c'est vrai » (dans ce contexte) qui n'est pas capturée par un simple « *yes* ». « C'est vrai » implique que B n'avait pas spécialement remarqué que C est fatiguée avant que A ne le fasse remarquer. L'anglais « *yes* » est plus neutre. On pourrait rendre la nuance par « *so you are* » en anglais.

Tant qu'on y est, « Pourquoi ? » sonne bizarre dans ce contexte en français alors que « *What happened?* » me paraît parfaitement naturel. J'aurais plutôt dit « Comment cela se fait-il ? » (« Comment ça se fait ? » en langage courant). On peut rendre la même bizarrerie en anglais en traduisant littéralement : « *Why?* ».

Answer (score 1):

The same context applies in English, "C'est vrai" means "It's true", so responding "it's true" to a yes/no question feels as weird in french as it does in english.

Answer (score 0):

Bonjour Roaman, 
Je voulais juste faire allusion à la langue de départ/source (LD) et celle d'arrivée/cible (LA),en l'occurrence l'anglais et le français.Il va sans dire que le transfert linguistique est invariablement tiraillé entre fildelité vis-à-vis de la langue source d'une part ( auteur, mots, texte, rythme...) et l'attente du lecteur de la langue cible, ici le français. A mon sens, c'est la fluidité de la langue cible et le communicatif qui doivent prendre le dessus.
Merci,depuis Londres.